# Javascript Capturing Groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling with capturing and non-capturing groups in Javascript.

I have the following string

```
var string = "#Blah blah blah\n#ENV:This is env note 1\n#MISC:this is a misc note\n#ENV:this is env note 2\n\n";
```

I would like to capture each text that starting with #ENV: and ending with new line, without capturing the '#ENV:' tag itself. (i.e. I want to return ["this is env note 1", "this is env note 2"]

I have tried the following:

```
var capture = string.match(/(?:#ENV)([^\n]*)/gi);
// Returns: ["#Blah blah blah", "#ENV:This is env note 1", "#MISC:this is a misc note", "#ENV:this is env note 2"]

var capture2 = string.match(/(?:(#ENV))([^\n]*)/gi);
//Returns ["#ENV:This is env note 1", "#ENV:this is env note 2"]
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Leo

Comment: Please include a link to documentation for the regex engine you are using.  It appears to have some non standard behaviors with regard to capture groups.  Actually, it seems to be completely ignoring all capture groups.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you are correct, I used `regex.exec(string)` instead and works like a charm.

Comment: You can answer your own question below so that others might benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Two regexs have same result, you have to cut `#ENV:` from result

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

Problem comes from `match` method.

The following code works instead

```
var regex = /#ENV:(.*?)\n/gi;
var match;
var result=[];
while(match = regex.exec(string)) {result.push(match[1]);}
```